# Playing songs downloaded into the cache directory

Tags: swift

Downloading an mp3 and saving it into the Library/caches folder works, But accessing it later doesn't.

Checking if the song *really* exists, i opened up Finder and went to the simulator folders. and my folder looks like this:

[image]

My song is located at: **Library/Caches/Digger/Flower.mp3**

Trying to access this using AVPlayer:

```
    let folderName = "Digger"
    let fileName = "Flower.mp3"
    let url = FileManager.default
        .urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        .appendingPathComponent(folderName).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    var urlString = url.absoluteString
    print("MyPath: \(urlString)")
    urlString.removeSubrange(urlString.range(of: "file://")!)

    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: urlString)!)

    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {

        player.play()
    }
```

But it doesn't work.

Simulator screenshot upon runtime:

[image: screenShot1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL handling is incorrect.

Replace these lines:

```
var urlString = url.absoluteString
print("MyPath: \(urlString)")
urlString.removeSubrange(urlString.range(of: "file://")!)

let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
```

with:

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
```

`url` already is the URL that you need. No need to try to convert it in any way.

For reference, use `url.path` to convert a file URL into a path string. And if you need to create a `URL` from a path string, use `URL(fileURLWithPath:)`, not `URL(string:)`. Only use `URL(string:)` with a string that has a URL scheme such as `file://`, `https://`, etc.